# Need advice on classification.

Tags: r, cross-validation

I would be grateful if someone can provide some insight into classification.

I have a data set which has a large number of feature > 5000 and 60 observations, with 13 classes. My data set has classes which repeat, lets say for example, I have the classes: A,B,C,D,E. In my data set I have A,A,A,A,A,B,B,B,B,B,C,C,C,C,C,D,D,D,D,E,E for the classes alone, each of which has different feature values. Should I treat this as one dataset to train for classification? or should I spilt the data so each class is repeated only once?

Another question I have is that I am using KNN classification and would like to cross validate KNN using K-fold to find the optimal K value. Should I apply PCA on the entire data set first, find the PC and use the rotation values from PCA as my input for the cross validation.

I am really stuck, any advice or help to apply me to solve this will be much appreciated.

P.s. if what i have written doesn't make sense i'll happily try my best to explain it differently - it is my understanding of it so far.

Many thanks in advance,
hp

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to classify something with 13 different classes. You have multiple observations for every class. If you want to be able to predict any new data you should train your classification model on all observations. Splitting it would result in multiple models that have no value on their own.

Applying PCA reduces the number of dimensions of your dataset. In your case you have > 5000 features, i.e. >5000 dimensions. This can be problematic both for prediction accuracy and computation time. It can be useful to run PCA before you do anything with the data. If you want to use it, I would de it before you do k-means (or any other model) especially because the choice of your optimal K will be different after applying PCA.

WHy do you want to apply PCA before using K-means? Condisering the fact that you have so many variables I would apply PCA first to and proceed as you suggested (apply k-means on the PC's).

Comment: Yes, they are different observations of the same object.

Comment: And what are you hoping to achieve with this analysis? Predict the class of new observations?

Comment: Yes, exactly that. Any advice?

Comment: I have changed my answer above.

Comment: Much appreciated makes sense. I have now applied the PCA, am i correct in JUST extracting the rotation values? and using this as my input data for the following steps thereinafter?

Comment: Also, i tried looking up normalization in PCA, i read setting scale =T does the normalization- based on standard deviation, is anyone aware if this is the same as applying a normalizaion function to the dataset, i.e. using (x-minx) /(max(x)-min(x))?

Comment: About PCA. The short answer is yes. But the question you should ask yourself is how many of those rotations (=dimensions) you want. The whole idea is that you want to reduce the number of dimensions. So you should look for the optimal number of values without losing to much information. There are structured was of doing that (e.g. looking at an 'elbow plot', google it). About scaling: that depends on the software you use. If you use R with prcomp I think it automatically centers and divides by the standard deviation. Not the min-max scaling you describe.

Comment: you've been a massive help, i would just like to clear the final hurdle. I am now aware that the rotation values are what i need, but in the PCA output for names(pca):  "sdev"     "rotation" "center"   "scale"    "x"    what is the difference between "rotation"  and "x" is it not the case that the rotation is the mapping from a higher dimension to a lower one whilst 'x' is the rotated values, in which case i should extract 'x' for my further analysis?

Comment: "rotation" is are the loadings. You use that to get the values of new observations. 'x" is indeed the actual rotated values of your current data (obtained by using the "rotation")